# profiles vs sharing rules

Tags: sharing, profile, owd, org-wide-defaults, sharing-rule

If user's Profile has Read only access on Contact and OWDs(Org Wide Defaults) for Contact is Public Read only and there is a sharing rule which gives read write access to all contacts to that User's Role.In this case will User get Read/Write access to All Contacts ? I know Sharing rules are used against OWDs to open up sharing.**Will Sharing rules overrides over Profile permissions ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Sharing rules open up access to records.  If the user's profile does not have edit on the contact object, he will not be able to edit the record.